# BeautifulSoup: get tag text behind another tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

How to find tag by another tag using BeautifulSoup? In this example I want to get for example '0993 999 999' which is in div right behind another div with 'Telefon:' text.

I tried to get it using this:

```
print parsed.findAll('div',{'class':"dva" })[3].text
```

But It does not work properly. I think there must be a way to tell BeautifulSoup that it is right behind 'Telefon' text or another way.

```
 <div class="kontakt">
        <h2 class="section-head">Kontaktné údaje</h2>
        <address itemprop="address"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" >
             <span itemprop="streetAddress" >SNP 12</span>, <span itemprop="postalCode" >904 01</span> <span itemprop="addressLocality" >Pezinok</span> </address>
        <div class="jedna">Telefon:</div>
        <div class="dva">013 / 688 27 78</div>
        <div class="jedna">Mobil:</div>
        <div class="dva">0993 999 999</div>
        <div class="jedna">Fax:</div
        <div class="dva">033 / 690 97 94</div>
        <div class="jedna">E-mail:</div>
        <div class="dva"><br /></div></div>
```

EDIT: I tried this, does not works neither.

```
tags = parsed.findAll('div',{'class':"jedna"})
for tag in tags:
    if tag.text=='Telefon:':
        print tag.next_siebling.string
```

Could you guys please give me a hint how to do that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = u"""html here"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find('div', text='Telefon:').find_next_sibling('div', class_='dva').text
print soup.find('div', text='Mobil:').find_next_sibling('div', class_='dva').text
```

Prints:

```
013 / 688 27 78
0993 999 999
```

FYI, you can extract the duplication and have a nice reusable function:

```
def get_field_value(soup, field):
    return soup.find('div', text=field+':').find_next_sibling('div', class_='dva').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print get_field_value(soup, 'Telefon')  # prints 013 / 688 27 78
print get_field_value(soup, 'Mobil')  # prints 0993 999 999
```

Hope that helps.