# Access value in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have made an HTML request from which I would like to retrieve specific elements, but I don't know how to access them with BeautifulSoup4.

Here is an example of the returned html:

```
<td valign="top" >
    <span class="recordAttribute" >Taxonomy</span>: Mollusca, Gastropoda, Littorinimorpha, Hydrobiidae, Hydrobia<br>
    <span class="recordAttribute" >Identifiers:</span> AF118324[sampleid]               <br>
    <span class="recordAttribute" >Depository</span>: Mined from GenBank, NCBI                    &nbsp;
</td>
```

I would like to access the element **AF118324** (which is the name after the *Identifiers* span class).

How could I access it? (without using a substring method of course)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup: get tag text behind another tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662053/beautifulsoup-get-tag-text-behind-another-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
html = '''
        <td valign="top" >
        <span class="recordAttribute" >Taxonomy</span>: Mollusca, Gastropoda, Littorinimorpha, Hydrobiidae, Hydrobia<br>
        <span class="recordAttribute" >Identifiers:</span> AF118324[sampleid]               <br>
        <span class="recordAttribute" >Depository</span>: Mined from GenBank, NCBI                    &nbsp;
        </td>
       '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
obj = soup.find('span', text='Identifiers:').nextSibling
print(obj)
```

Which prints:

```
 AF118324[sampleid]
```